# Where should init scripts be placed in Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, init.d, amazon-linux

In the Amazon Linux 2 [release notes](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/release-notes/), Amazon advises that initscripts should no longer exist in `/etc/init.d`

> Amazon Linux 2 uses the systemd 219 init system to bootstrap userspace and manage system processes. It is available as /sbin/init and replaces the System V-style init system that was available in the previous generation of Amazon Linux. As a result, initscripts should no longer exist in /etc/init.d. systemctl {start|stop|restart} SERVICE_NAME.service should be used in its place. Additionally, service SERVICE_NAME {start|stop|restart} is compatible with both Amazon Linux AMI and Amazon Linux 2.

We rely on an initscript to auto-start Supervisor when the instance boots. Is there a viable alternative under the systemd 219 init system?

Comment: Have a look at EC2 [user-data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Comment: systemd entirely replaces supervisor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new way is to create **systemd unit file** for your application or startup script. It may seem like an overkill for simple startup scripts but it is the way that most current Linux distros adopted - Amazon Linux, Redhat, Ubuntu, Debian, they all use *systemd* so it pays to know how to do it properly.

Have a look here for example: [**Creating and modifying systemd unit files**](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/chap-managing_services_with_systemd#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: As systemd is over eight years old now, most software you might run as a service already includes sample systemd units, or such units are available on the Internet.